# c++ efficient data structure for appending data with overwriting?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I would like some container that I can very efficiently append a variable amount of elements to, but be able to trigger something so I can start overwriting from the beginning. With a `std::list` it would look something like this:

```
while(whatever)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < randNumber; ++i)
        list.push_back( foo() );
    //now want to reset
    list.clear();
}
```

The problem is `list.clear()` is linear time whereas I would really just like to go back to the beginning and start overwriting from there...I tried with vector using `vector[index++] = foo()` and replacing the clear with `index = 0` but you cant predict `randNumber` so this does not work...what can I use instead to achieve this?

BTW vector clear does not seem to be constant time even if I have a trivial destructor:

```
struct rat
{
    rat(int* a, int* b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}

    int *a_;
    int *b_;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint64_t start, end;

    int k = 0;
    vector<rat> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9000; ++i)
        v.push_back(rat(&k, &k));

    start = timer();
    v.clear();
    end = timer();

    cout << end - start << endl;
}
```

Comment: Pixie dust should take care of that

Comment: what do you mean by "you cant predict `randNumber`", and why would that cause `std::vector` to be useless for your goal ?

Comment: `vector` sounds like exactly what you need...

Comment: I don't think there is anything better than `vector` for your need.

Comment: The size of a `std::vector` is not determined at compile time. It will expand as needed to accomodate each new element you `push_back`. I believe that the expansions are also "permanent", inasmuch as the buffer space will remain allocated to the vector for its lifetime even if you call `clear` unless you demand it be shrunk.

Comment: And a `list` could be made to work with a little additional logic that kept a "current location" iterator which may or may not be the end of the list. If it pointed at an existing element, it could overrwrite it and advance to the next, otherwise it would call `push_back` as normal.

Comment: @Rook that idea sounds good...the problem with vector is that again i am trying not to have to call clear as i could care less about calling the destructor for everything in there already..all i want is to go back to beginning and start overwriting.

Comment: Then you should either a) only store simple datatypes in your structure (such as an integer index into some other table structure) or b) make a writer function that either overwrites or pushes back, depending on whether the current writer cursor is at the end or not. Its only a few lines of code

Comment: do you want to overwrite old nodes or you want a brand new container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `std::list` for `std::vector` in your code. `push_back` will increment the size as needed, and `clear` will remove all elements from the container. Note: `std::vector<>::clear()` takes linear time on the size of the container, but the operations are destruction of the stored elements (if they have a non-trivial destructor) which you need to do anyway. For types with trivial destructors, `std::vector<>::clear()` behaves as a constant time operation.

Comment: For trivial destructor clear is O(1)? I was not aware of this, how does it know whether they have trivial destructor? If it's not user defined?

Comment: I am not seeing constant time clear as you say (check edit to my original question)

Comment: A destructor is trivial if it is not user provided, it is not virtual and all the destructors of it's bases and data members are trivial. Consider `struct X { int x; };`. As of the time you see in your test, it will depend on the optimization level and the standard library implementation. In particular in VS2010 `clear` calls `erase( begin(), end() )`, and that in turn calls `_Destroy_range` which uses type traits to dispatch to one of two overloads: either an empty function or a loop that calls the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an upper bound on `randNumber`? If so, you could use `std::vector::reserve()` to speed up things. This way, you would have append in O(1) and remove in O(1).

NOTE! If the vector contains data-types with non-trivial destructor, `clear` takes O(n). However, if the destructor is trivial, `clear` takes O(1).

Comment from stl_constructor.h:

```
/**
 * Destroy a range of objects.  If the value_type of the object has
 * a trivial destructor, the compiler should optimize all of this
 * away, otherwise the objects' destructors must be invoked.
 */
```